# A most notable story on justice with Umar ibn al-Khattab, Sa'd ibn Abi Waqqas, and Anushirvan

Tags: source-identification, justice

I have heard the following narration (I summarized it, and some parts may be paraphrased)

> While Sa'd ibn Abi Waqqas was the governor of Damascus at the time of
> Umar ibn al-Khattab, he wanted to extend a mosque in Damascus. So
> he bought the lands around the mosque. A Jewish man, however, refused to
> sell his property. Finally, Sa'd ibn Abi Waqqas simply took the
> ownership of the land and had his men pay the Jewish man. There was
> nothing the Jewish man could do. One day, he told what happened to his
> Muslim neighbor. The neighbor told him to go to Medina, and find caliph
> Umar: “I am told that he is a most just ruler.”
>
> So the man goes to Medina, asks about Umar when he gets there, people
> point at a man under a tree. He goes to the man, introduces himself,
> and narrates what happened. Umar writes a note, and tells the man to
> give it to the governor of Damascus. The note says: **I am not any less
> just than [Anushirvan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khosrow_I).** The man looks at Umar, looks at the note,
> thanks him and leaves.
>
> When he arrives at Damascus, he is hesitant about what to do. A
> modest man gave him a one-line note which would hardly change
> anything. Still, he invested a lot in this matter already, so he goes
> to the governor, says he has seen caliph Umar, and gives him the note
> that Umar gave. As soon as he reads the note the governor's face pales,
> his hands starts to shake. He says: “consider your land is given to
> you.”
>
> The man so surprised that his curiosity about
> what the hell is happening overwhelms his joy of having his land back.
> He begs the governor: “Please, just tell how this note made change your
> mind in an instant!”
>
> The governor says, here is why. Before Islam, Umar and I went to Persia for trade. While we were in
> Persia, a group of gangsters came and took our camels and our money.
> There was nothing we could do; there were too many of them. Back at the
> inn we were staying, we told what happened to the inn-keeper. The
> inn-keeper told us to go to King Anushirvan, that he was a most just
> king. So we went to the king. We were given a translator. We told out
> story to the translator, the translator narrated the story to the
> king. The king ordered that we should each be given a bag of gold.
> Back at the inn, we told the inn-keeper what happened. The inn-keeper
> was slightly puzzled. He said there must be some misunderstanding:
> “Come, tomorrow we go together, and this time I will be your
> translator.”
>
> Next day, the three go to the King again. The inn-keeper narrates what
> happened. The King's face pales. He orders that two bag of golds shall
> be given to each of us, and our camels also. The king added: “when you
> are leaving the city, one you shall leave from the East entrance and
> the other from the West entrance.”
>
> We were of course most puzzled. Back at the inn, the inn-keeper told
> us the story. He said, when we narrated him what happened, he realized
> that gang was the gang of the king's son, and the king's second
> man. When he narrated the story to the king, he of course realized who
> was who.
>
> When I was leaving the city I saw to men hanged. There was a big crowd
> around them. I asked about them and someone said, these two are the
> son and the second man of the king, they robbed traders. There was
> another man hanged at the other entrance, he was the translator, who
> mistranslated our story so as to protect them. The king ordered the
> execution of his own son!
>
> Now you see what Umar means with his note. He is telling me that he will
> execute me just like the king executed his son.
>
> Upon hearing all this, the Jewish guy not only granted his land, but
> he also became a Muslim.

What is the strongest source of this narration?

Comment: At least according to Wikipedia, Saad ibn Abi Waqqas (RA) was the governor of Kufa at the time of Umar (RA). And I don't think it was generally the practice of Quraish to trade in Persia so I find that part of the story strange as well.

Comment: I translated the Şam from the dictionary. It could be the case that Kufa was in that place at those times. Also, Wikipedia says Sasanian King; so that could be somewhat different that Persia, at least for the matter of trading. All in all, if the king whom he is told, I would say it is normal that anyone would go to his country for trade business.

Comment: Sham refers to greater Syria. Kufa is pretty far away. It's in Iraq. Quraish's basic trade route was Syria in the summer and Yemen in the winter. But, it's probably not impossible some of them went to Persia as well. Sassanian is simply a dynasty of Persia.

Comment: So far I found a narrative about 'Omar defending a Jew, but the story you' ve shared clearly mismatches this event as there's nomentioning of any other sahabi in this context.

Comment: Maybe you should share the original source from where you get this. Wikipedia says that Anushirvan died in 579. Umar and Saad ibn Waqas were born years after that so it is not possible that they met him.